# How can I load a particular widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, widget

when the user registers or signs in, auth changes are listened to.Signing out function works well. Home() is loaded when the user logs out. But when the user signs in/ registers, the message 'user is not null' is printed, but the HomeScreen() widget is not loaded. Please help.

```
  class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final user = Provider.of<User>(context); // getting user from main.dart which gets the user from 
  stream
print(user);
print('here in wrapper');

if(user == null) // the user is logged out
{
  print('User is null');
  return Home();

}
else               // user is registered or signed in
{
  print('User is not null');
  return HomeScreen();
}
```

}
}

Comment: Can we see the User class?

Comment: class User
{
  final String uid;
  User({this.uid});
}

Answer (score 0):

Your using firebase right? Implement the logging out function to dispose the current user.

Comment: I am able to see the HomeScreen() when i press back button.

Comment: are you unable to see your home screen when? try to share your code maybe I can fix it